# an error in tcl and ns2

Tags: tcl, ns2

i`m working with ns2 and TCL language and i deal with a problem :

```
ns: _o159 stop: 
    (_o159 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o159 cmd stop"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o159" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o159 stop"
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Your errors can be caused by any faulty simulation.tcl : Just a typical error output from libotcl. Please edit your question to show the simulation.tcl ( Or upload the file and add a **shared** link to your question.)

Comment: There's an error that was picked up from the `stop` method. All the rest of the stack trace there is just due to the OTcl method dispatch machinery (which “helpfully” doesn't say _which class_ owned the method that failed) so all we can really say is that some `stop` method went wrong, and the error message itself (which should be the first line of the trace) tells us very little indeed.

Comment: thanks. my error had originated my stops and i used Agent but i must use Application.